# How to Exclude files from coverage?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-views

*I am running my unit tests. But I want to exclude some folders and files during tests.*

Here is my **.coveragerc** file

```
[run]
 branch = True
 source = .
 omit =
  Amazon_customers/.coveragerc
  amazon_customers/tests
  Amazon_customers/__init__.py
  Amazon_customers/urls.py
  Amazon_customers/wsgi.py
  amazon_customers/test_utils/*
  /migrations/
  /manage.py/
```

I need to exclude these files but it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Finally got the solution:*

```
[run]
 omit =
 */environment/*
 */migrations/*
  Amazon_customers/*
  manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration file as below. it's better to provide the full path of file or folder/directory

```
[run]
 branch = True
 source = .
 omit =
  /home/myuser/Amazon_customers/.coveragerc   # file skip
  /home/myuser/amazon_customers/tests/*       # directory skip
```

For more information read
https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source.html#execution

Comment: Thank you @Anjaneyulu Batta. I have tried this solution but it is not working. Also, i already following this documentation.

Comment: @zamansandhu replace `/home/myuser/Amazon_customers/.coveragerc` with your file fullpath. I've just given an example. same for the directory also.